# How to make list lookup faster in this recursive function

Tags: python

I have a recursive function which creates a `json` object

```
def add_to_tree(name, parent, start_tree):
    for x in start_tree:
        if x["name"] == parent:
            x["children"].append({"name":name, "parent":parent, "children":[]})
        else:
            add_to_tree(name, parent, x["children"])
```

It is called from another function

```
def caller():
    start_tree = [{"name":"root", "parent":"null", "children":[]}] # basic structure of the json object which holds the d3.js tree data
    for x in new_list:
        name = x.split('/')[-2]
        parent = x.split('/')[-3]
        add_to_tree(name, parent, start_tree)
```

new_list is list which holds links in this form

```
/root/A/
/root/A/B/
/root/A/B/C/
/root/A/D/
/root/E/
/root/E/F/
/root/E/F/G/
/root/E/F/G/H/
...
```

Everything is working fine except for the fact the run times grows exponentially with with the input size.
Normally new_list has ~500k links and depth of these links can be more than 10 so there is lots of looping and looks involved in the `add_to_tree()` function.

Any ideas on how to make this faster?

Answer (score 2):

You are searching your whole tree each time you add a new entry. This is hugely inefficient as your tree grows; you can easily end up with a O(N^2) searches this way; for each new element search the whole tree again.

You could use a dictionary mapping names to specific tree entries, for fast O(1) lookups; this lets you avoid having to traverse the tree each time. It can be as simple as `treeindex[parent]`. This'll take some more memory however, and you may need to handle the case where the parent is added *after* the children (using a queue).

However, since your input list appears to be sorted, you could just process your list recursively or use a stack and take advantage of the fact you *just found the parent already*. If your path is longer than the previous entry, it'll be a child of that entry. If the path is equal or shorter, it'll be a sibling entry to the previous node or a parent of that node, so return or pop the stack.

For example, for these three elements:

```
/root/A/B/
/root/A/B/C/
/root/A/D/
```

`/root/A/B/C` does not have to search the tree from the root for `/root/A/B`, it was *the previously processed entry*. That'll be the parent call for this recursive iteration, or the top of the stack. Just add to that parent directly.

`/root/A/D` is a sibling of a parent; the path is shorter than `/root/A/B/C/`, so return or pop that entry of the stack. The length is equal to `/root/A/B/`, so it is a direct sibling; again return or pop the stack. Now you'll be at the `/root/A` level, and `/root/A/D/` is a child. Add, and continue your process.

Comment: I had the same idea but i was not sure how it would work. Suppose the recursion goes down 10 levels. Then if i make a copy of 'x' and use if in the next call, will it correctly assign the children in 'start_tree'?

Comment: @user3804483: no need to make a copy; just pass in the parent dicitonary directly. Assign to that dictionary `children` list, then process the next items from the input list for any children, passing in the current dictionary, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested this, but it looks like the loop does not stop when an insertion has been made, so every entry in `new_list` will cause a recursive search through all of the tree. This should speed it up:

```
def add_to_tree(name, parent, start_tree):
    for x in start_tree:
        if x["name"] == parent:
            x["children"].append({"name":name, "parent":parent, "children":[]})
            return True
        elif add_to_tree(name, parent, x["children"]):
            return True
    return False
```

It stops searching as soon as the parent is found.

That said, I think there is a bug in the approach. What if you have:

```
/root/A/B/C/
/root/D/B/E/
```

Your algorithm only parses the last two elements and it seems that both `C` and `E` will be placed under `B`. I think you will need to take all elements into account and make your way down the tree element by element. Anyway that is better since you will know at each level which branch to take, and the correct version will be much faster. Each insert will be `O(log N)`.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/3316409/dvaergiller, i have taken care of the fact that links should end with '/'. I excluded that part as it was not necessary.

Comment: Whether or not it ends with `/` is not the matter. I edited the answer to reflect that. The problem is that both `C` and `E` have a `B` as parent but they are different `B`'s which have different parents themselves. The algo does not handle that correctly.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't read properly the first time. You make a good point. I'll modify the code. Thanks